Laravel Spark with Paddle - Something went wrong
I implemented Laravel Spark + Paddle payments. It took me more than 2 hours to set it all up, and in the end... after I go to my "Billing" page in the app and try to pay... a modal opens with the message "Something went wrong. Please try again later. If the issue persists, you can contact our support team using the button below."
What to do here?

If you look at the errors in Chrome DevTools, you should see that the seller ID is not accepted by Paddle. Why is that? Most likely because your page is not sending it? Why is that? Because Laravel Spark didn't tell you to add it to your .ENV file.
Add this to your .ENV file:
PADDLE_SELLER_ID=xxx

You can get this ID from your Paddle portal, under Developer Tools > Authentication.
--
I had to GUESS this. So I really hope this helps someone spend less time on this than I did.
